# How to edit user input in Python 3.3.4

Tags: python, variables, input

I have a program where the user inputs a number for each certain criterion. This number is then made into a variable, which is supposed to change throughout the program.
For example, I have one called "strength":

```
strength = int(input("Strength:"))
```

Later on, I try to add 10 to this number, but I couldn't. 
I tried putting:

```
strength == strength + 10
```

It did not come up with an error message, but it did not change the variable. Please can someone help!!

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solved your problem. That is the best way to thank someone in SO world.

Answer (score 2):

Use one equal sign for assignment:

```
strength = strength + 10
```

Two equal signs is for [comparison](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strength = strength + 10
```

`==` is used for equality and you should use `=` for assignment.